# How to calculate received signal power for a Multi-User MIMO OFDM system?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, signal-power, mimo

I have a Multi-User MIMO system where there are 2 users served by a base station. The base station consists of 64 transmit elements and the users are equipped with linear antenna array consisting of 3 elements. The channel that I use is One-Ring channel model which is NLOS model rich in multipath with scatterers.

Hence, I have a channel matrix $H_1$ of dimension 234x64x3 for each user (234 OFDM subcarriers are used). We send a single data stream to each user, and they are precoded using JSDM technique (Joint Spatial Division Multiple Access). Considering the basic equation $y=H^HVD+z$ where $V$ is the precoded matrix, $D$ is the data symbols and $z$ is the noise, how can we calculate the received power pertaining to each user?

At the receiver, I have the $y$ matrix for each user after performing equalization as $Y_1$ (234x10x1) which is (No. of subcarrier x No. of OFDM symbols x No. of streams). With this $Y$ matrix, can I calculate the received power? If I take the squared magnitude of $y$, it is still a 3D matrix and I do not know what is the exact power reported by user-1.